# Get ARN of EC2/EBS Volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-ebs

I need an EBS Volume ARN to specify it when creating a resource set with Route 53 Recovery Application Controller. But EBS Volumes don't have this attribute.

[image]

Here's an example description of an EBS Volume:

In:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --volume-ids vol-03303bf453f8d7ee5
```

Out:

```
{
    "Volumes": [
        {
            "Attachments": [],
            "AvailabilityZone": "ap-southeast-1a",
            "CreateTime": "2021-11-03T15:43:40.087000+00:00",
            "Encrypted": false,
            "Size": 1,
            "SnapshotId": "",
            "State": "available",
            "VolumeId": "vol-03303bf453f8d7ee5",
            "Iops": 100,
            "VolumeType": "gp2",
            "MultiAttachEnabled": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the format that worked for me:

```
arn:[partition]:ec2:[region]:[account-id]:volume/[volume-id]
```

For example:

```
arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-1:123456789123:volume/vol-03303bf453f8d7ee5
```